# How to get Hibernate ResultTransformer to work with entity that have relations with other entities

Tags: hibernate, resulttransformer

i have **Employee** , **Role** , **Department** domains

- **Employee** , **Role** have **many to many** relationship.
- **Employee** , **Department** have **many to one** relationship.

  ```
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumn(name = "fk_department_id")
      private Department department;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "employee_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
  private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);
  ```

-Requirement: get **all users** with **role admin**:

so here's what i am trying to do:

```
List<Employee> employees = getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery(
                        "select"
                                + e.id as id,e.first_name as firstName,e.password as password
                                + "from employee e,employee_role er,role r where e.employee_id=er.employee_id and er.role_id=r.role_id and r.name='ROLE_ADMIN' ")
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class))
                .list();
```

**Problem**: i can get all the properties easily as in above query, except for the **Department** property(there's column fk_department_id in employee table) and the **roles** property (there's a join table employee_role), any ideas **how to get them** with the **query** and set them in the bean with **ResultTransFormer** or i will have to do that in a separate queries and set each property separately ?

Comment: do you mind using **HQL** instead of **SQL** and **ResultTransformer**?

Comment: i can't because employee_role generated table don't have a mapped entity.